# Excel - If a Cell contains a value from an Array, extract that value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I can't find a way to make this work. I hope that maybe someone can help me with this.

```
The cell A2 contains the following: "Star Wars Lotion Pump"

My array contains (C1:C5) the following:
C1: Categories
C2: Pen
C3: Clock
C4: Watch
C5: Lotion
```

In the cell B2 the formula should return "Lotion" or in case there is no match just a "".

Comment: what if there are two or more in the string?

Comment: Just show the first one or the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$5,A1)),0)),"")
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1:C5,A2)),C1:C5,""))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.  This should return multiple keywords.